# Where is published errata for Essentials?

Tags: dnd-4e, errata

Has Wizards of the Coast published errata yet for any of the Essentials books?

I'm pretty sure that I already know the answer to this -- no errata has yet been published for **Heroes of the Fallen Lands** or **Heroes of the Forgotten Kingdoms** -- but I wanted to make sure I haven't overlooked anything.

(If errata does get published, I'll link to it from this question, just so we have an archival pointer to it.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Essentials errata used to end up with all the rest of the [updates](https://web.archive.org/web/20151105055901/http://archive.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/updates). The archive used to break it down by book.